# Nutch [1.x] - What is the difference between webgraph and readlinkdb commands?

Tags: apache, web-crawler, nutch

I have difficulties in understanding the working of Apache Nutch 1.x and the documentation is not helping much.

Basically, I want to generate the inlinks and outlinks from the crawled data.

From Nutch wiki:

### ReadLinkDB:

> Readlinkdb is an alias for org.apache.nutch.crawl.LinkDbReader
>
> This reader class enables us to to obtain various information from
> within a linkdb. The two types of information we can retrieve is
>
> A dump of the whole linkdb which is then written to a text file for
> easy viewing. Specific information relating to a specific URL.

### WebGraph:

> WebGraph is an alias for org.apache.nutch.scoring.webgraph.WebGraph
>
> This class Creates three databases, one for inlinks, one for outlinks,
> and a node database that holds the number of in and outlinks to a url
> and the current score for the url.

After running both the commands, the output files generated are of different size. WebGraph command is reading the segments directory to generate the inlinks and outlinks, while the ReadLinkDB command reads the linkDB.

Could you please help me to understand the difference?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Both LinkDb and WebGraph are first data structures

- the LinkDb contains for every page the inlinks and anchor texts, it's a map `⟨URL => [⟨from_URL, anchor_text⟩, ...]⟩`. It enables indexing of [anchor texts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anchor_text).
- the WebGraph is more complex and built out of 3 substructures: InlinkDb, OutlinkDb, NodeDb. It contains more information than LinkDb, also link timestamps and types, link counters and a score. It's purpose is to incrementally build the hyperlink graph and run a link rank algorithm on it.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!